# Share data to all views in laravel5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I have the following problem, I want to share an array to all views in my project so I followed the documentation and it works fine, but I want to get the authenticated user in service provider boot function and it always return null ? 
any suggestions ?

this is my code

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider 
{
  /**
   * Bootstrap any application services.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public $myusers;

  public function boot()
  {
     $origLat=\Auth::user()->lat;
     $origLon=\Auth::user()->lng;
     $dist=5;
     $lon1=$origLon-$dist/cos(deg2rad($origLat))*73.2044736;
     $lon2=$origLon+$dist/cos(deg2rad($origLat));
     $lat1=$origLat-($dist/73.2044763);
     $lat2=$origLat+($dist/73.2044763);

     $id=\Auth::user()->id;                            
     $pictures=User::find($id)->pictures;
     $this->myusers = DB::table('users')->select(

            DB::raw("*,
                        3956 * 2 * 
              ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(($origLat- lat)*pi()/180/2),2)
              +COS($origLat*pi()/180 )*COS(lat*pi()/180)
              *POWER(SIN(($origLon-lng)*pi()/180/2),2)))*1.609344 
              as distance"
              ))    
                    ->where('users.id', '!=', \Auth::user()->id)
                    ->whereBetween('lng',[$lon1,$lon2])
                    ->whereBetween('lat',[$lat1,$lat2])
                    ->having("distance", "<", "$dist")
                    ->orderBy("distance") 
                    ->get();

                view()->share('myusers', $this->myusers);
  }

  /**
   * Register any application services.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function register()
  {
    //
  }
}
```

Comment: I have shared the code above any suggestions ?

Comment: What returns null? `Auth::user()->id`? Have you tried `Request::user()->id`, try var dumping the `Auth::user()`, what do you get? You should probably add a check to see if they are auth'd before you send it to the view.

Comment: I have tried all this and it always return a null .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, at this point the Laravel application request lifecycle works in such a way that when the `boot` method of the `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` class is executed the session is not yet initialised (since that's done in a middleware that is executed after the `boot` method).

Since the authentication systems needs the session in order to get the authenticated user, in your particular case you can't use `view()->share()` successfully there (although it's the recommended approach). Instead you can use an alternative approach by doing that in a middleware. Here are the steps that you can follow to make this work:

**1.** Create a middleware class, let's call it `LoadUsers`, by running this command:

```sh
php artisan make:middleware LoadUsers
```

**2.** That will generate a class in `app/Http/Middleware/LoadUsers.php`. Now you just need to move your code from the `AppServiceProvider` to the `handle` method of the middleware:

```php
class LoadUsers
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        // Your code that shares the data for all views goes here

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**3.** Next you need to register the middleware with the `App\Http\Kernel` class. You can add it to the `web` group from `$routeMiddleware` if you want to apply the middleware to all routes that that use that or create your specific group or route middleware. So something like this if you want to add it to `web`:

```php
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        ...
        // Make sure to add this line is after the
        // StartSession middleware in this list
        \App\Http\Middleware\LoadUsers::class,
    ],
    ...
];
```

Now you should have the proper shared data for all your views that can depend on `Auth::user()`.

Comment: Thanks! , you are awesome .